# Different Markdown rendering between preview and saved result

Tags: support, bug, markdown-rendering

I have this Markdown content to render an asterisk in italic:

---

[image]

---

In the preview it looks good and the result is as expected, but when I save the changes I get:

---

[image]

---

Why doesn't it render correctly when I save the changes and why is there that difference between preview and saved changes?

Comment: A workaround is to use HTML instead (`<em></em>`).

Comment: *why is there that difference between preview and saved changes?* because the implementation on the server side is in C# and the one on the client is in Javascript. 2 implementations, same spec, unique bugs in each implementation.

Comment: Another workaround is to use the Markdown escape character (``\``) to just escape the inner asterisk: `*(\*)[12]*`. This may not work in comments, but [does in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364614).